# how to getSharedPreferences in dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

i want to read file in dialog

can any one guide me how to achieve this?

when i use

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
in dialog it gives me error "method is undefined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Context` to access the preferences.

```
context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the context using `super.getContext()`:

```
super.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```